# Are There Musical Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, music

Are there any Jedi who are musicians in the Star Wars universe? Is playing an instrument considered acceptable within the Jedi order/lifestyle?

Canon or Legends acceptable.

Comment: Obi Wan could sing like a Krayt Dragon - does that count?  Also, we do know that music appreciation is acceptable within the Jedi order (Anakin attends a concert in Ep.III - granted it was at Palpatine's invitation, but nobody knew he was a Sith at the time so they were probably fine with it), so it doesn't seem unreasonable they'd be able to play music as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Padawan [**Cal Kestis**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cal_Kestis) plays the [Seven-stringed hallikset](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Seven-string_hallikset) in the game *[Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Jedi:_Fallen_Order)*. It apparently belongs to another former Jedi Knight, [**Cere Junda**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cere_Junda).

In the *Jedi Academy* series of books (and graphic novel) we encounter [**Tionne Solusar**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tionne_Solusar), one of Luke's pupils. She plays a wide variety of instruments.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Wars: Encyclopedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[Jedi Academy: Leviathan, Part I](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Academy:_Leviathan)</sup></sub>

**[Ulaha Kore](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ulaha_Kore)** also plays and composes music in the same series of books and comics.

> Ulaha Kore said lightly. Ulaha was a delicate young Bith, with musical
> talents that admitted her to any number of intelligence-rich social
> occasions. Ulaha looked careworn, her posture so slumped that Mara
> barely could see her large eyes under her protruding, hairless head.
>
> <sub><sup>[The New Jedi Order: Balance Point](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order:_Balance_Point)</sup></sub>

And in [*Specter of the Past*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Specter_of_the_Past) we learn that **[Valin Horn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Valin_Horn)** plays the [Chordokeylo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chordokeylo).

> “Don’t disturb him,” Karrde said. “Perhaps we’ll have time later. Is he still keeping up with his music?”
>
> “Like a mynock with his tail on fire,” Booster said wryly. “I just bought him a new chordokeylo-he’d already worn out his first one.